# taskdef class org.eclipse.acceleo.parser.compiler.AcceleoCompiler cannot be found using the classloader

Tags: eclipse, ant, acceleo

I have this line of code in an ant bulider:

```
<taskdef id="acceleoCompiler" name="acceleoCompiler" classname="org.eclipse.acceleo.parser.compiler.AcceleoCompiler" classpathref="Framework.libraryclasspath" >
    </taskdef>
```

It is complaining with the following:

```
taskdef class org.eclipse.acceleo.parser.compiler.AcceleoCompiler cannot be found using the classloader
```

It also says the same thing as an error when i attempt to run the ant build. What is the problem and how do i fix this?

---

I have the following in my ant builder:

```
<path id="Framework.classpath">
    <path refid="Framework.libraryclasspath" />
</path>

<path id="Framework.libraryclasspath">
<pathelement location="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins/org.eclipse.acceleo.parser_3.2.0.v20111027-0537.jar"/>
</path>
```

And it is still not working. With the same error as before.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set path with `Framework.libraryclasspath` id (via help of `path` task, for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My path variables were wrong. Correcting those fixed the problem. However, i am now experiencing a different problem. Will post new question and put link to it from here.

[The next question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246245/ant-builder-build-failed-einstance)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the jar org.eclipse.acceleo.parser in your classpath. Please note that this task is used to run an Acceleo generator out of Eclipse, if you want to use the Acceleo generator in Eclipse, you just have to right click on your main module and then select Run as an Acceleo Application. You can find more documentation in the Help -> Help Contents menu.

Regards,

Stephane Begaudeau

Comment: Hi, you can find on the following screenshot my configuration (https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-hkvC0xVvpHQ/Ts0KCF1fkxI/AAAAAAAAAoA/7LY1kUndimU/ant.png). You can also try to use the maven based build which I personally find easier to use, you can find the details on my blog (http://sbegaudeau.tumblr.com/post/6517419281/acceleo-3-1-maven-and-tycho) and a working example on an Acceleo generator on github: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Java-Generation

Comment: Have to use ant. And my setup looks the same as yours... and it is still not working.